# Arc length for continuous implicit differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length, implicit-function

We have a continuous differentiable function defined as $$F(x,y)=0$$And I am looking for a formula for its arc length between $x$ values $a$  and $b$. Doing a quick search, I could only find formulae for vector functions and functions with parametrizations. I was thinking of writing $y$ in terms of $x$ so that $F(x,f(x))=0$, but that will make this function a single variable and not a multivariable function as desired.

Comment: For a general implicit function, one $x$-value may correspond to multiple $y$-values, so the curve between $x=a$ and $x=b$ may not be uniquely defined. With parametrisation this would not be a problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _'We have a continuous differentiable function defined as F(x,y)=0'_?  Is it that $F$ itself is continuous and differentiable? Or that there exists an implicit $f$ such that $F(x,f(x))=0$, or possibly $F(f(y),y)=0$, and that $f$ is continuous and differentiable?

Comment: @CiaPan $F$ itself, yes.

Comment: Well, the $F$ alone continuous and differentiable does not seem to guarantee any well-defined _arc_. As an example, $F(x,y)=\cos(x^2+y^2)$ equated to zero would define an infinite set of concentric circles, and $F(x,y)=\sin x\cdot \sin y$ will give an infinite grid of vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: @CiaPan Hmm, it is difficult to pinpoint exactly what I want in a rigorous manner. How about this: for every $x$, there is a finite amount of $y$ such that $F(x,y)=0$

Comment: That does nothing at all to improve matters. The usual way one handles the ambiguity in defining an implicit function $y = f(x)$ from $F(x,y) = 0$ is to specify that $f(x_0) = y_0$ where $(x_0, y_0)$ is a given point with $F(x_0, y_0) = 0$ and $\nabla F(x_0, y_0) \ne 0$. $f$ will then be uniquely defined as a continuous function on some neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see why the way you suggest works, but what is wrong with my method? I am not saying you’re wrong, I just don’t know why.

Comment: Why do you think your method would work? If I asked you to tell me the number I am thinking of, without any other clues, you obviously couldn't. But if I told you there were only finitely many choices, and even listed them out, would that ensure you could figure it out? Obviously not, unless there was only one choice. Just because I cut down some on the ambiguity doesn't mean I've eliminated it. In CiaPan's examples, replace $\cos$ and $\sin$ with a polynomial with multiple real roots. You still get a collection of concentric circles, and a grid of lines, though only finitely many of each.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Okay, thanks!